# Getting TinyMCE Tinybrowser to upload directly into CakePHP webroot

Tags: cakephp, upload, tinymce

I have the Tinybrowser plugin working with TinyMCE for file uploads. Everything is working great so long as I upload into the /app/uploads/ folder. Unfortunately this means that images (etc) aren't available to display from the application front end. I haven't had any success setting up a symlink between the two locations (php symlink() fails silently) so it looks like my only option is to upload into the /app/webroot/uploads/ directory instead.

The difficulty here is that when the upload path is changed to /app/webroot/uploads/, the application goes into an infinite recursion. I guess this is to do with the .htaccess rules on /webroot/ but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any ideas what the problem might be and what I can do to fix it? Any help appreciated.

---

.htaccess mod_rewrite is essentially the cakephp default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

#far-future caching
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: post your htaccess code.

Comment: Have you tried symlinking on system level, e.g. on linux `ln -s ....`

Comment: I don't have system access, unfortunately, and exec() is disabled. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is only a url problem. The url for the directory /app/uploads/ is specified in the tinymce directory or in the plugin directory. You can change the url.

i got another upload plugin working in tinyMCE and the change of the url is working. I think there is no problem with the .htaccess

Comment: Marking this as accepted as I did end up using a different upload plugin (specifically TinyFCK - http://freshmeat.net/projects/tinyfck/ ). There didn't seem to be any way to make Tinybrowser work for me at all. It's possible that the problem had something to do with cakeAuth or session support or something like that but I couldn't narrow it down. Thanks!